# Combine 2 response if models.field is same for two requests

Tags: django, python-2.7, if-statement, for-loop, django-models

I have Request data model with `id`, `type` and `language`. I am doing the following process.

```
def email_me(requests):`
    string = ""
    for request in requests.all():
        string = """
        ID: %d
        Type: %s
        """ % (request.id, request.type)
    <some code for sending an email>
```

I am running this function into a view where I get the `requests`

Here `string` will give data for each individual Request database column. What I want to do is if `type` is same for two string I want to combine them in one email. For example `type = customer` I want to send data in one email.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using python dictionary:

```
to_send = dict()
for request in requests.filter(type=type):
    string = """
    ID: %d
    Type: %s
    """ % (request.id, request.type)
    if request.type not in to_send:
        to_sent[type] = ''
    to_send[type] += string

for type, string in to_send.iteritems():
    # send you mail
    pass
```

Please note if you have too many data inside that table there could be more optimized solution, I gave you an easy/quick one